# How to create an alphabetized drop down menu in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to re-write this code so that the drop down menu is alphabetized:

```
$activeProjectDropdown.="<option value=''>Select Project</option>";
$getInfo = "SELECT id, customer, job_name, haul_info 
            FROM dispatch_jobs 
            WHERE (:mydate BETWEEN delivery_date AND delivery_date_end) 
            ORDER BY customer, job_name";

$result=DB::run($getInfo, ['mydate' => $myDate]);
while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
    if(!empty($row['haul_info'])) {
        $haulinfo = "($row[haul_info])";
    }else{
        $haulinfo = "";
    }

    if($checkit == $row['id']){
        $woot = 'selected=selected';
    }else{
        $woot = '';
    }

    $customerName = pdo_getName('name', 'customer', "$row[customer]");
    $activeProjectDropdown.="<option value='$row[customer]|$row[id]' $woot>$customerName $haulinfo</option>\n";
}
```

In this code the query returns some rows from the database where customer is a numeric code which isn't in any kind of alphabetical order.  Further down in the code a function called `pdo_getName` is called which takes a column of `name` table of `customer` and the id from `$row['customer']` and queries the database, returning the stringified name of the customer.  Because the name isn't being retrieved until later on down the loop I'm having trouble figuring out a way that I can alphabetize the `$activeProjectDropdown`.  I've tried putting the `$customerName` and drop down code into an associative array, then sort that by `$customerName` and concat everything into a string, but that didn't work because there are duplicate keys.  Down that same path, I could potentially have a nested array but I figure there must an easier solution I'm missing.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well write a JOIN query and get all the data in one query

Comment: ___PS___ As `pdo_getName()` is not vanilla PHP, most of us will have no idea what its doing

Comment: If that `pdo_getName()` is heading back into the database inside that `while` loop then I would definitely do what Riggs is suggesting above. Query it all in the same query. Running SQL inside of a loop is very very very rarely a good idea. Please share that function's code and we can help out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a JOIN query and get all the data in one query then you can sort on the customers name as I think you are asking to do.

This will improve performance as well as simplify the code.

```
$getInfo = "SELECT dj.id, dj.customer, dj.job_name, dj.haul_info 
                    c.name
            FROM dispatch_jobs dj
                LEFT JOIN customer c ON c.id = dj.customer
            WHERE (:mydate BETWEEN dj.delivery_date AND dj.delivery_date_end) 
            ORDER BY c.name, dj.job_name";
$result=DB::run($getInfo, ['mydate' => $myDate]);

while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
    if(!empty($row['haul_info'])) {
        $haulinfo = "($row[haul_info])";
    }else{
        $haulinfo = "";
    }

    if($checkit == $row['id']){
        $woot = 'selected=selected';
    }else{
        $woot = '';
    }

    $activeProjectDropdown.="<option value='$row[customer]|$row[id]' $woot>$row[name] $haulinfo</option>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY customer ASC, job_name
```

This sorts everything by costumer (ascending) first, and then by job_name (ascending, which is the default) whenever the costumer fields for two or more rows are equal.

more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)